# SpringBoot Multiple Data Source JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following code

**Entity**

```
 @Entity
    public class Employee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        long id;

        @Column(name="first_name")
        String firstName;

        @Column(name="last_name")
        String lastName;

        @Column(name="salary")
        int salary;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="address")
        Address address;

    ..... setter & getter

    }
```

**Repo**

```
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class EmpService {

    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository empRepo;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager em;

    public List<Employee> findAll(){
        return empRepo.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private EmpService empService;


    @RequestMapping("/abcd")
    public List<Employee> findAll(){
        return empService.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Data Source Configuraion (Primary)**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="primaryDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return tm;
    }

    @Bean(name="primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(DataSourceConfiguration.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

**Secondary Data Source Config**

```
 @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
public class DS2Configuration {

    @Bean(name="secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")

    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(secondaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return tm;
    }

    @Bean(name="secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(DataSourceConfiguration.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=MYSQL
logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG

# Primary DataSource configuration
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa
datasource.primary.username=root
datasource.primary.password=root

# Secondary DataSource configuration
datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa2
datasource.secondary.username=root
datasource.secondary.password=root

# Disable Spring DataSource auto-initialization
spring.datasource.initialize=false

server.port=8081
```

When I am actually running function findAll() from EmpService, it is always using primary datasource even when i am specifying  secondary entitymanagefactory as

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    EntityManager em;
```

How to resolve this?
P.S. - Please do not share blog links for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your Repository classes in two different directories. And change the

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example".....)
```

line in both the places where you are configuring the datasource. That should fix your problem of
*code runs but uses always primary Data Source*

Regards

Comment: Yes it worked. But is it not possible to give same basePackage to two config files and specify config at run-time.

Comment: I am not sure because @componentscan basically works with packages. But looking at the documentation(http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html), You can give it a try for excludeFilters. I have not tried it personally. Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there are more than one beans of type `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` to help spring boot decide which bean to prefer

annotate the `bean` with **`@primary`** annotation

[`@primary` official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)

Comment: It's complaining about non-unique entityManagerFactories not datasources. His datasource setup looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Primary on this method :  primaryEntityManagerFactory()

By the way, I think primaryTransactionManager() and equivalent secondary methods are superfluous, the factory bean methods return the same thing.

You also need to define a transactionManager per entityManager e.g.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(yourPrimaryEntityManagerInjected);
    return tm;
}
```

Comment: You need to define a transaction manager bean for each entity manager. I'll add it to my reply.

Comment: Done this.  
 @Bean(name="primaryTransactionManager")
 @Primary
 public JpaTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
     JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
     tm.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
     return tm;
 } but still same error

Comment: Also when I have removed transactionManager Definition from both Config file, code runs but uses always primary Data Source even when I have specified secondary on Service class using @Autowired
 @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
 EntityManager em;

Comment: Turn on debug for org.springframework and see how the autowiring is happening. As far as the transaction manager is concerned, have a separate java config for it and  rather than doing this primaryEntityManagerFactory().get‌​NativeEntityManagerF‌​actory() just use the injected factory i.e. this primaryEntityManagerFactory. Good luck, the debug logging should help you work out what is going on.

Comment: Now no error is coming. I have added transactionManager in both the configs. But the issue is everytime it is using primary data source. What am i now missing?

Comment: Try separating your datasource config into a separate configuration and injecting them, and also debug to check that the separate datasource properties have been bound. 

Is it using the same datasource or a different one with the same properties ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139342/discussion-between-paulnuk-and-ankit-bansal).